# Running water and stand still water impact

Tags: classical-mechanics

I jumped from height $\:\rm h$ into a moving water canal of breadth $\:\rm b$ and infinite length with velocity $v$ and in a different fall, I'm plummeting into a swimming pool of length $l$ breadth $b$ and depth $d$. Assuming both water have same density, which fall impact will take the most toll on the body? I personally felt swimming pool have greater impacts. But can someone help me with required equations and conceptual explanation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Water is an incompressible fluid, which means when a force acts on it, the force resonates all the way through and across the water body. When a human slams into water from a great height, the fall is considered fatal, why? As you accelerate through the fall and gain momentum/velocity, your kinetic energy rockets through the fall. You can calculate the force of impact using: $$F\delta t = m\delta v$$
When the $t$ in the above equation is small, the force is greater since they are inversely proportional, and even though water is a fluid, it needs time get out of the way fast enough to absorb the impact and cushion you to safety (since motion and velocity is a function of time), at high final velocity $v$ before contacting the water surface, there isn't much time for fluidity so the body experiences a normal reactional force approximately equal to one you'll get if you were to impact a solid ground. So velocity and time matters a lot in dictating whether you survive the fall or otherwise regardless of how colossal the water body is or how fast it's moving.